Python asyncio: Concurrent write tasks frequently canceled, how to ensure alternating execution?
I'm developing an asynchronous cache system in Python using asyncio. I have two concurrent write operations that I want to alternate, but currently, only one side tasks are frequently canceled
Here is my current implementation in python3.10:
import asyncio
from collections import defaultdict
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from copy import deepcopy
from datetime import datetime


class LocalCacheUserToken:
    _g: dict[str, dict] = {}
    _tasks: dict[str, asyncio.Task] = {}
    _locks: defaultdict[str, asyncio.Lock] = defaultdict(asyncio.Lock)
    _write_lock = asyncio.Lock()

    @classmethod
    @asynccontextmanager
    async def acquire_lock(cls, key: str):
        async with cls._locks[key]:
            yield

    @classmethod
    async def get(cls, key: str):
        async with cls.acquire_lock(key):
            value = deepcopy(cls._g.get(key, None))
        return value

    @classmethod
    async def setex(cls, key: str, time: int, value: dict):
        async with cls._write_lock:
            async with cls.acquire_lock(key):
                print(f"[{datetime.now()}] {value=} get lock")
                if key in cls._tasks:
                    cls._tasks[key].cancel()

                cls._g[key] = value

            task = asyncio.create_task(cls._delay_delete(key, time, value))
            cls._tasks[key] = task

    @classmethod
    async def _delay_delete(cls, key, time, value):
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(time)
            async with cls.acquire_lock(key):
                del cls._g[key]
            cls._tasks.pop(key, None)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print(f"[{datetime.now()}] Deletion task for {key=}, {value=} was cancelled")


async def p(a: LocalCacheUserToken):
    while True:
        print(f"[{datetime.now()}] {await a.get('test')=}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def write(a: LocalCacheUserToken, k: str):
    for i in range(20):
        await a.setex("test", 5, {'value': f'{k}->{i}'})
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)


# 示例使用
async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(p(LocalCacheUserToken))
    asyncio.create_task(write(LocalCacheUserToken, k='test1'))
    asyncio.create_task(write(LocalCacheUserToken, k='test2'))

    await asyncio.sleep(10)


asyncio.run(main())

outputs:
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] await a.get('test')=None
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->0'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->0'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->1'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->1'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->0'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->2'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->2'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->1'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->3'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->3'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->2'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->4'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->4'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->3'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->5'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->5'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->4'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->6'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->6'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->5'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->7'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->7'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->6'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->8'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->8'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->7'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->9'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->9'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->8'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->10'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->10'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->9'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->11'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->11'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->10'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->12'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->12'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->11'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->13'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->13'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->12'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->14'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->14'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->13'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->15'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->15'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->14'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->16'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->16'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->15'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test1->17'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.054703] value={'value': 'test2->17'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.070327] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->16'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.070327] value={'value': 'test1->18'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.070327] value={'value': 'test2->18'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.070327] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->17'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.070327] value={'value': 'test1->19'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.070327] value={'value': 'test2->19'} get lock
[2024-06-28 01:42:35.070327] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->18'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 01:42:36.056942] await a.get('test')={'value': 'test2->19'}
[2024-06-28 01:42:37.063445] await a.get('test')={'value': 'test2->19'}
[2024-06-28 01:42:38.064713] await a.get('test')={'value': 'test2->19'}
[2024-06-28 01:42:39.069732] await a.get('test')={'value': 'test2->19'}
[2024-06-28 01:42:40.077492] await a.get('test')=None
[2024-06-28 01:42:41.087926] await a.get('test')=None
[2024-06-28 01:42:42.103530] await a.get('test')=None
[2024-06-28 01:42:43.107391] await a.get('test')=None
[2024-06-28 01:42:44.108523] await a.get('test')=None

What is reason of this problem and how can i fix it?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

The problem is that the write(LocalCacheUserToken, k='test2') is cancelling the task from write(LocalCacheUserToken, k='test1') in the same iteration of the event loop. This means that cls._delay_delete('test1', *, *) does not get executed because the task that it was scheduled in has already been cancelled. Because cls._delay_delete(...) isn't executed, neither is the print statement print(f"[{datetime.now()}] Deletion task for {key=}, {value=} was cancelled"). To allow the print statement to be executed even when cls._delay_delete(...) is cancelled you can add a "done" callback to the task and remove the try/except from cls._delay_delete(...), as follows:
...
    @classmethod
    async def setex(cls, key: str, time: int, value: dict):
        async with cls._write_lock:
            async with cls.acquire_lock(key):
                print(f"[{datetime.now()}] {value=} get lock")
                if key in cls._tasks:
                    cls._tasks[key].cancel()

                cls._g[key] = value

            def on_delay_delete_done(task):
                if task.cancelled():
                    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] Deletion task "
                          f"for {key=}, {value=} was cancelled")

            task = asyncio.create_task(cls._delay_delete(key, time))
            task.add_done_callback(on_delay_delete_done)
            cls._tasks[key] = task

    @classmethod
    async def _delay_delete(cls, key, time):
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        async with cls.acquire_lock(key):
            del cls._g[key]
        cls._tasks.pop(key, None)
...

Now we get the intended output:
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.088757] await a.get('test')=None
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.088836] value={'value': 'test1->0'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.088887] value={'value': 'test2->0'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.088952] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test1->0'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.099279] value={'value': 'test1->1'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.099466] value={'value': 'test2->1'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.099549] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->0'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.099572] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test1->1'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.109923] value={'value': 'test1->2'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.110013] value={'value': 'test2->2'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.110125] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->1'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.110163] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test1->2'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.120440] value={'value': 'test1->3'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.120602] value={'value': 'test2->3'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.120685] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->2'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.120709] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test1->3'} was cancelled
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.130982] value={'value': 'test1->4'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.131126] value={'value': 'test2->4'} get lock
[2024-06-28 00:47:22.131210] Deletion task for key='test', value={'value': 'test2->3'} was cancelled

A general word of advice would be to try to make this code simpler before proceeding because it was pretty hard to reason about. It's also possible that it needs to be this complicated. Good luck if that's the case :)

thank you for your detailed answer. it feels like a queue and i only consider when one job is running and it recieve a cancel signal at the same time so it prints some info. but the truth is asyncio execute task one by one, just like a queue, the task is add to the queue and waiting for executing and cancel. so the situtation what i thought never happed

Yep, you're correct asyncio does use a queue. That's the right way to think about it. In the Python source code here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c3677befbecbd7fa94cde8c1fecaa4cc18e6aa2b/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L2011-L2029 you can see that it's the self._ready queue. In your original code cls._delay_delete was already cancelled and consequentially skipped by the if handle._cancelled: continue in the Python source code. The second thing that asyncio does is poll for I/O events. This means scheduled callbacks can be executed while waiting for non-blocking I/O operations.
